# excplicit formula of iterates of an interval exchange

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be an interval exchange transformation of $[0,1]$. Is there an explicit formula giving $f^k(0)$ in function of $k$?

If not, are there particular cases where this formula is simple? (except when $f$ is a rotation).

I am mostly interested in the case when $f$ is periodic, and with the permutation ABC -> CBA where A,B,C are intervals of different lengths (with the interval B being translated).

For this particular interval exchange, we have: $f^k(0)=k_1 \lambda_1+k_2 \lambda_2 +k_3 \lambda_3$. where the $\lambda_i$ are the translation vector of $f$ on each of the three intervals. Is it possible to have an estimate the $k_i$?

Comment: What's an interval exchange transformation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_exchange_transformation

Comment: http://combinat.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/iet/tutorial.html

Comment: What do you mean $f$ is periodic? that $f^n(x)=x$ for all $x$ for some $n$?

Comment: that there exists $n$ such that for any $x$, $f^n(x)=x$. it implies that the lengths of intervals are rational.

Comment: Why would the lengths of the intervals have to be rational? The implication in the other direction is obvious, but it seems like you could take a periodic interval exchange map and break it up into one with irrational lengths that is essentially the same. Is that ruled out by the definitions or some other standard assumption?

Comment: maybe you are right, replace "it implies" by "it is implied". I am only interested in the case of rational lengths.

Comment: is Rauzy-veech induction relevant for this problem?

Comment: I guess, but I am not sure, that by explicit formula you mean a computable function F that depends on f^k(0), for k<m and m is fixed, such that F(n)=f^n(0). I think you need to specify what exactly you want to mean by explicit formula.

Comment: i do not understand your question. if $f$ is a rotation of angle $\alpha$, then $f^n(0)=n \alpha$, and i want an analogous formula when $f$ is an interval exchange (or at least, some information of some kind).